# Implementing a custom data format in DXA in Java

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

In the documentation for DXA is [a description of how to create a custom data format](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-CFEC9E0E-7295-483E-977E-A024297919E8).

Unfortunately, it doesn't mention how to tackle this in Java. What would the equivalent technique be in Java?